# Supervisor starts more processes with one command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, process, supervisord

I have been investigating [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) for use on my project.

In [documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) it states that is is possible to start more then one process with one command. Having configuration such that it `program:process_name` represent “homogeneous process group” if `numprocess` is set to more then one.

If I set `numprocess` to 2 for the example below, the supervisor will try to start the same process twice. Right?

```
[program:cat]
command=/bin/cat
process_name=%(program_name)s
numprocs=1
directory=/tmp
umask=022
priority=999
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
startsecs=10
startretries=3
exitcodes=0,2
stopsignal=TERM
stopwaitsecs=10
stopasgroup=false
killasgroup=false
user=chrism
redirect_stderr=false
stdout_logfile=/a/path
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_events_enabled=false
stderr_logfile=/a/path
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_logfile_backups=10
stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stderr_events_enabled=false
environment=A="1",B="2"
serverurl=AUTO
```

How to configure it to start different processes from different directories?

For example I want to start both mongo and nodejs with one command in supervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two configuration files, one for MongoDB and one for Node. 
Place them into `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`, call them `mongo.conf` and `node.conf` with something like this:

> node.conf

```
[program:node-app]
numprocs=1
directory=/your/app/directory
command=/usr/bin/node server/server.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
environment=NODE_ENV=production
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/somelog.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/somelog.out.log
user=<youruser>
```

> mongo.conf

```
[program:mongod]
command=/usr/bin/mongod --port 27017 --quiet --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --logappend
autostart=true
user=root
startsecs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/mongod.log
```

Of course you need to adjust the values per your environment.

Then you will be able to control them via `supervisorctl` command or to restart everything with `service supervisor restart`

Example: `supervisorctl restart node-app`